# Why is Entity Framework Core trying to Convert my string key to an Integer?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, entity-framework-core

**UPDATED**

```sql
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[bmaitempic](
    [itemnmbr] [char](31) NOT NULL,
    [fileseq] [int] NOT NULL,
    [filename] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [filedata] [varbinary](max) NULL,
    [Compressed File Data] [varbinary](max) NULL    
 CONSTRAINT [PK_BMAITEMPIC] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [fileseq] ASC,
    [itemnmbr] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

I have a simple model with a compound key:

```
[Table("bmaitempic")]
public class EcommerceItemImages
{
    [Column("itemnmbr")]
    [StringLength(31)]
    public string Itemnmbr { get; set; }

    [Column("fileseq")]
    public int Fileseq { get; set; }

    [Column("filename")]
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string Filename { get; set; }

    [Column("filedata")]
    public byte[] ImageData { get; set; }
    
    [Column("Compressed File Data")]
    public byte[] CompressedImageData { get; set; }
}
```

In my DbContext is like this:

```
public class EntityContext : DbContext
{
    public EntityContext(DbContextOptions<EntityContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
        
    }

    public DbSet<EcommerceItemImages> Images { get; set; }
    
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<EcommerceItemImages>()
            .HasKey(x => new { x.Itemnmbr, x.Fileseq });
    }
}
```

I have a method in a Winforms button press event where I get an exception on SaveChanges():

```
    private void btnConvert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _context.Images.Load();

        var images = _context.Images.Local.ToBindingList();

        foreach (var image in images)
        {
            if(image.ImageData != null)
                image.CompressedImageData = Compress(image.ImageData);
        }

        var count = _context.SaveChanges();

        MessageBox.Show($@"{count} images compressed.");
    }
```

The Exception is:

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
  Source=Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational
  StackTrace:
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.Execute(IRelationalConnection connection)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.Execute(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalDatabase.SaveChanges(IList`1 entries)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(IList`1 entriesToSave)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(DbContext _, Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChanges(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChanges()
   at CompressImages.Form1.btnConvert_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in D:\Projects\NewEcommerce\CompressImages\Form1.cs:line 43
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, WM msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)

  This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    [External Code]

Inner Exception 1:
SqlException: Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '1-A3483A                       ' to data type int.
```

'1-A3483A                       ' is the `Itemnmbr` of the first record and is part of the compound key. Why is EntityFramework Core trying to Convert it to an Integer?

**UPDATE**

Log entry:

```
Failed executing DbCommand (56ms) 
[Parameters=[@p1='16384', @p2='1-A3483A ' (Nullable = false) (Size = 31), @p0='0x1F8B080000000000000AAD5707501340974E202111A497808418A44A535A0202...' (Size = 8000)], 
CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30'] 
SET NOCOUNT ON; 
UPDATE [bmaitempic] SET [Compressed File Data] = @p0 WHERE [fileseq] = @p1 AND [itemnmbr] = @p2; 
SELECT @@ROWCOUNT;
```

Comment: Which EF Core version? Which provider?

Comment: that is not EF, the column type is probably int in the database, it is a SqlException

Comment: Please share the CREATE TABLE statement for the table in use

Comment: @ilkerkaran No, the Column type in the data base is CHAR(31)

Comment: Again, please share the full CREATE table script - is the column order here wrong?

.HasKey(x => new { x.Itemnmbr, x.Fileseq });

Comment: @ErikEJ EntityFramework Core Version 5.0.7

Comment: @ErikEJ I reversed order in the .HasKey in my code but I still get the same error.

Comment: So check the SQL statement to see what EF is trying to store in which column. That's always the first thing to do when a `SqlException` occurs.

Comment: I finally got EF Core loggin to Serilog... I will post the revelent log at the end of my Question.

Comment: The SQL statement would suggest that the error is coming from the `[itemnmbr] = @p2` part. And the error you have provided is the kind of error that happens when you try to compare a non-numeric string value to a number. Are you _absolutely sure_ that the column in your database is not a numeric type? Are there any triggers/constraints/etc that might be coming into play along with this UPDATE statement?

Comment: @JLRishe You are right. There was a UPDATE trigger. Once I disabled it the error was fixed. Please put in Answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For completeness:

Solution: I had a sql UPDATE Trigger on the table. I disabled it. Fix was provided by @LJRishe in a comment.